# The PowerShell ISE equivalent for Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, editor

I'm just starting to learn Python 3 on Windows. I looked and googled but I can't find a GUI tool to write and execute Python code the way I do with PowerShell and the PowerShell ISE app.

Is there such tool for Python?

I found Visual Studio Code but I can't run/execute code with it, or can I?

Comment: Like Python's integrated IDLE?

Comment: hehe -2 expected.. no love for the clueless noobie.. also I found this: 
 https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors#Windows-Only_Editors

Comment: Simon. Have you ever seen Powershell ISE?

Comment: No it's more the clarity of your question.  Wait OH you're after one of those.

Comment: PS ISE interface is separated in 2: Code on the top, exec output on the bottom. You can execute specific lines (or even specific portion of a line) from the code and see the output, best way to learn. https://4sysops.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/PowerShell-ISE-tabs.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple IDLE to choose from:

I'll start with the integrated IDLE:

[image]

Good syntax highlighting, preinstalled with Python.  You can open it in any Python file by right clicking and selecting "Open in IDLE". Also includes in a separate window an integrated shell that allows running/debugging.

Notepad++:

[image]

A very powerful text editor.  Supports syntax highlighting for multiple languages, allows you to run your script (may require a little setup) and debug.  Allows multiple windows, debugging, powerful extensions such as colour pallets and auto complete.

Sublime text:

[image]

Allows scripts to be run from inbuilt shell includes debugging.  Highly customisable, change background colours, syntax highlighting, autocomplete.  Multiple windows as well as file explorer (shown above) and allows extensions.  It's paid but there is a trial.  Definitely worth a look.

If you want a versatile command line editor (note it does not allow execution) you might want to go with VIM.  It was very popular once...

[image]

Also there is Notepad but doesn't really do anything.

### Also note that Visual Studio will also work as well as the above. It allows running through an inbuilt shell that allows running/debugging.

You could also go after a separate Python installation with one included:

[image]

This is Ipython's Interactive shell.  It offers many features including excellent debugging.

Anaconda is also an option:

[image]

It allows you to debug scripts from the console.

Comment: @ToastMan  Pleased I was of use.  Sorry some of those images don't show actual Python code but they do show they give you a feel of what the actual IDLE are like. :-)

Comment: It's a perfect start for me Simon.. I think I will try to go with Notepad++ for now :) thanks again

Comment: @ToastMan  I've tried it, it's good.  Sublime Text is OK as well and the Python IDLE is also amazingly good for what it is.  Since it's already installed you may want to check that out as well (if you have not already)  I wouldn't go for VS code it's overrated (unless you need the compiler or C#), but still it's only in my opinion